# How to jump to last page of pagination upon page load when using DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I've been fiddling around this problem for the past 5 hours or so and cant seem to get this to work. is there any way we can go to the last page of pagination upon page load as i want the latest record to be shown? im using dataTable version 1.10.19 by the way, been looking at different forums and sites for a solution. Below is my code snippet for calling the DataTable API::

```
var table = $('#item_history_table').DataTable({
        ajax: base_url + 'item/get_item_history/1',
        order: [],
        paging: true,
        ordering: false,
        columns: [
            { data: 'date' },
            { data: 'customer' },
            { data: 'in' },
            { data: 'out' },
            { data: 'balance' }
        ]
    });
```

This is what i've done already:

- tried using fnPageChange( 'last' ) but apparently, its already deprecated as of version 1.10
- tried using iDisplayStart but i dont know the last number of my record as its dynamic since i will add more record in the future so cant hard code the number
- tried using table.page('end').draw(false); but it doesn't work
- tried using table.page('end').draw(); but it also doesn't work

Any help is greatly appreciated! thanks in advance!

Comment: It would have weird appearance from the user experience point of view. Wouldn't that make more sense to invert sorting order instead, so that your last records will be rendered on the first page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of methods to achieve your goal.

One of them is trough using [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) option:

```
initComplete: function(){
                 this.api().page('last').draw('page')
              }
```

Above will switch to the last page once upon table initialization.